Prove that if eigenvalues are all different then eigenvectors are linearly independent
I was trying to work out a proof of the fact that if eigenvalues are all different, then the eigenvectors are linearly independent. Is the following proof fine or does it have errors ?
Given that $ \mathbf{A v}_i = \lambda_i \mathbf{v}_i$, $i \in \{1,2,...,n\}$, where $ \mathbf{A}$ is $n \times n$ and $ \mathbf{v}_i$ is $n \times 1$. Hence $\mathbf{v}_i$ is an eigenvector of $\mathbf{A}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$. At the least, two eigenvalues can be different. At the most, all $n$ eigenvalues can be different. Let the set of distinct eigenvalues be $\{ \lambda_1, \lambda_2, ..., \lambda_r\}$, where $2 \leq r \leq n$. The corresponding set of eigenvectors is $\{ \mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, ..., \mathbf{v}_r\}$.
Consider scalars $c_1, c_2,  ...  ,c_r$ such that $c_1 \mathbf{v}_1 \ + \ c_2 \mathbf{v}_2 \ + \ ... \ + \ c_r \mathbf{v}_r = \mathbf{0} $. We define $\mathbf{c} = [c_1 \ c_2 \ \cdots \ c_r]^T$. Absorbing the constants $c_1, c_2,  ...  ,c_r$ into the eigenvectors gives,
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{y}_1 \ + \ \mathbf{y}_2 \ + \ ... \ + \ \mathbf{y}_r = \mathbf{0}        \tag{1}       
\end{equation}
In the above, $\mathbf{y}_i = c_i \mathbf{v}_i$. Further, $ \mathbf{A v}_i = \lambda_i \mathbf{v}_i$ implies
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{A} \mathbf{y}_i = \mathbf{A} (c_i \mathbf{v}_i) = c_i (\mathbf{A} \mathbf{v}_i) = c_i (\lambda_i \mathbf{v}_i) = \lambda_i (c_i \mathbf{v}_i)= \lambda_i \mathbf{y}_i
\end{equation}
Hence, we have, $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{y}_i = \lambda_i \mathbf{y}_i$.
Then,
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{A y}_1 \ + \ \mathbf{A y}_2 \ + \ ... \ + \ \mathbf{A y}_r = \mathbf{0} 
\end{equation}
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
 \lambda_1 \mathbf{y}_1 \ + \ \lambda_2 \mathbf{y}_2  \ + \ ... \ + \  \lambda_r \mathbf{y}_r  = \mathbf{0}     \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Multiplying Equation (2) by $\mathbf{A}$ again, we get
\begin{equation}
\lambda_1^2 \mathbf{y}_1 \ + \ \lambda_2^2 \mathbf{y}_2  \ + \ ... \ + \  \lambda_r^2 \mathbf{y}_r  = \mathbf{0} \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Repeatedly multiplying by $\mathbf{A}$ gives,
\begin{equation}
\lambda_1^k \mathbf{y}_1 \ + \ \lambda_2^k \mathbf{y}_2  \ + \ ... \ + \  \lambda_r^k \mathbf{y}_r  = \mathbf{0} \tag{4}
\end{equation}
where $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Equation (1) is:
\begin{equation}
 \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{y}_1 & \mathbf{y}_{2} & \cdots & \mathbf{y}_{r}  
 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{0}
\end{equation}
Equation (2) is:
\begin{equation}
 \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{y}_1 & \mathbf{y}_{2} & \cdots & \mathbf{y}_{r}  
 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}  \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \vdots \\  \lambda_r \end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{0}
\end{equation}
Equation (4) is:
\begin{equation}
 \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{y}_1 & \mathbf{y}_{2} & \cdots & \mathbf{y}_{r}  
 \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1^k \\ \lambda_2^k \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_r^k \end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{0}
\end{equation}
We define the vector $\mathbf{p}_k$ as:
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{p}_k = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1^{(k-1)} \\ \lambda_2^{(k-1)} \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_r^{(k-1)} \end{bmatrix} \tag{5}
\end{equation}
Therefore, the vectors $\mathbf{p}_1,\mathbf{p}_2, ..., \mathbf{p}_k$ belong to the null space of the matrix $\mathbf{Y} = [\mathbf{y}_1 \ \mathbf{y}_{2} \ \cdots \ \mathbf{y}_{r}] $. Since $\mathbf{y}_i$ is a $n \times 1$ vector, the matrix $\mathbf{Y}$ is $n \times r$. Now, suppose we generate a set of vectors $\mathbf{p}_1,\mathbf{p}_2, ..., \mathbf{p}_r$. We inspect whether the vectors are linearly dependent or independent i.e. we wish to inspect the following:
\begin{equation}
    \gamma_1 \mathbf{p}_1 \ + \ \gamma_2 \mathbf{p}_2 \ + \ \cdots \ + \ \gamma_r \mathbf{p}_r = \mathbf{0}      \tag{6}
\end{equation}
Equation (6) in matrix vector form is:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & \lambda_1 & \cdots & \lambda_1^{(r-1)} \\ 1 & \lambda_2 & \cdots & \lambda_2^{(r-1)} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\ 1 & \lambda_r & \cdots & \lambda_r^{(r-1)} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \gamma_1 \\ \gamma_2 \\ \vdots \\ \gamma_r \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \tag{7}
\end{equation}
Succinctly, Equation (7) can be written as:
\begin{equation}
 \mathbf{M} \mathbf{\gamma} = \mathbf{0}  \tag{8}
\end{equation}
The determinant of the $r \times r$ square matrix $\mathbf{M}$ is non-zero when all the eigenvalues i.e. $\lambda_i$'s are different. For example, for $r=3$, the matrix $\mathbf{M}$ is:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M}_3 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \lambda_1 & \lambda_1^2 \\
1 & \lambda_2 & \lambda_2^2 \\
1 & \lambda_3 & \lambda_3^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
The determinant of $\mathbf{M}_3$ is $(\lambda_2 - \lambda_1)(\lambda_3 - \lambda_1)(\lambda_3 - \lambda_2)$ which can be equivalently represented in cyclic order of terms as $(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2)(\lambda_2 - \lambda_3)(\lambda_3 - \lambda_1)$. This determinant is non-zero when $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ are all different. Note that at most one eigenvalue can be zero. Hence, the difference of two eigenvalues is never zero.
The matrix $\mathbf{M}$ is called the Vandermonde matrix. A general expression for its determinant is:
\begin{equation}
Det(\mathbf{M}) = \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq r}^{} (\lambda_j - \lambda_i)
\end{equation}
The determinant of $\mathbf{M}$ being non-zero implies that $\mathbf{\gamma} = \mathbf{0}$. Therefore, the set of vectors $\mathbf{p}_1,\mathbf{p}_2, ..., \mathbf{p}_r$ is linearly independent. This implies that the nullity of the matrix $\mathbf{Y}$ is $r$. From the rank-nullity theorem, the rank of $\mathbf{Y}$ is $0$. Note that $\mathbf{Y}$ is a $n \times r$ matrix with $2 \leq r \leq n$. The only matrix that has rank zero and nullity equal to the number of columns in the matrix is the zero matrix in which all elements are zero. It therefore follows that $\mathbf{Y}$ is the zero matrix. Now, given that by definition none of the eigenvectors i.e. $\mathbf{v}_i$'s are null vectors, for the matrix $\mathbf{Y}$ to be the zero matrix, one must necessarily have $\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{0}$. Nothing was assumed about the coefficients $c_i$'s. It has been demonstrated that all of them must necessarily be zero when the eigenvalues are distinct. Since $\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{0}$ is the only possible solution, it follows from the relation $ c_1 \mathbf{v}_1 \ + \ c_2 \mathbf{v}_2 \ + \ ... \ + \ c_r \mathbf{v}_r = \mathbf{0} $ that the eigenvectors are linearly independent.

Please ask this at Maths, where I am sure it has been definitely asked and answered. This is not a question related to statistics.

Thanks. I will ask in Maths.

Please don't just cross-post. Rather, click on "Flag" and ask the moderators to migrate your question. Thank you!

From $(7)$ and the definition of $\mathbf{p}$, you get immediately that $\lambda_i=\gamma$ for all $i$.

Thanks for the comment @TonyK. Indeed I need not proceed to the direction cosines.

The set of vectors $\mathbf{p}_1,\mathbf{p}_2, ..., \mathbf{p}_k$, where $k > n$ cannot be linearly independent. They are vectors in an $n$ dimensional space, so at most $n$ vectors can be linearly independent. I like your idea for this proof. If I find time I will try to make it work.

@Steen82 Thanks for your comment. I have modified the proof.

You should add some clarification as to why $\mathbf{p}_1,\mathbf{p}_2, ..., \mathbf{p}_k$ are linearly dependent. At this point it's basically handwaving, and that's often a source of errors (e.g.: Can we really choose $c_1,...,c_n$ to be any real number? And it still doesn't assert that $k\le n$)

The matrix $M$ is called a Vandermonde matrix and the determinant is calculated similarly to the formula for $M_3$ above.

You prove $YM=0$, so $M^t Y^t =0$ (where $Q^t$ denotes the transpose) and therefore $Y^t = \left(M^t\right)^{-1}0=0$. Completing the proof.

@Steen82 Thanks for your comment. I was searching for a general expression for the determinant of M. I did not know it is called the Vandermonde matrix. I will include a general expression for its determinant.

This is an interesting idea but unfortunately it does not work, for (at least) two independent reasons:

When you argue that $p, q_1, \dots q_n$ are linearly dependent you cannot conclude that the coefficient of $p$ in a linear dependence must be nonzero, and in fact the $q_i$ are linearly dependent by definition since they are all multiples of the same vector $c$. So there is a linear dependence but it's just, for example, $\lambda_j q_i - \lambda_i q_j = 0$, and $p$ need not participate at all.

To define that square root at the end requires the $\lambda_i$ to be real, but they could be complex (so that denominator could be zero), and in more abstract linear algebra could be elements of an arbitrary field.


Up until equation 2 you are on one of the possible right tracks. The idea from here is to continue repeatedly applying $A$, which gives
$$c_1 A^k v_1 + \dots + c_n A^k v_n = 0$$
or
$$c_1 \lambda_1^k v_1 + \dots + c_n \lambda_n^k v_n = 0.$$
This is a more interesting set of linear dependencies you can try to do something with. There are various ways to finish from here (try working out some examples for $n = 3$). Completely different and more abstract approaches are also possible. Note also that to save notation you can actually absorb the constants $c_i$ into the eigenvectors $v_i$, which are only defined up to scale anyway, so you can instead work with the simpler system of equations
$$\lambda_1^k v_1 + \dots + \lambda_n^k v_n = 0.$$

Thanks for your answer. I will try to correct the proof.

I have modified the proof. Please let me know if there are still any errors in it.

@Tirthankar: this still does not work, there's no contradiction yet. You have not actually proven that the vectors $p_i$ remain linearly independent when $k > n$, and in fact they can't (this has nothing to do with the proof by contradiction you're trying to run). Like any vectors of length $n$ there is a linear dependence between them eventually (which I encourage you to try to find, it is quite interesting).

There is a general pitfall here in trying to write down proofs by contradiction: anytime you've made a mistake you think you're done with the proof! This is why I suggest that people should avoid proofs by contradiction and just try to prove things directly. That way you're only ever considering true statements and you can check your work on examples (which is impossible with a proof by contradiction since there aren't any examples).

Thanks for your comment. I have the modified the proof yet again. If possible, please go through it.

@Tirthankar: you have not proven that $p_1, \dots p_n$ are linearly independent! And in fact this won't be true if any of the $c_k$ are equal to zero. Here's a hint: your definitions are slightly off. You should absorb the $c_k$ into the $v_k$ and define $p_k$ to be the vectors with entries $\lambda_i^{k-1}$. With these definitions it is now true that $p_1, \dots p_n$ are linearly independent but to prove it will involve more work than what you've done so far. You can see here for a big hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

I have updated the proof. Please take a look.

@Tirthankar: yes, this works! The only small issue now is to clean up some of the language at the end; you need to say that since the $c_i$ were arbitrary, and we showed that they were always equal to zero, that shows that the eigenvectors are linearly independent.

I have modified the text. Thanks for all the help.

It's looking pretty good now!
Those $c_i$ are still haunting you - choosing $c_i=0$ results in $\mathbf y_i$ not being an eigenvector by definition, so you have to name that case explicitly (i.e. " $\mathbf y_i$ is either an eigenvector again, or 0").
In the final spurt you're contradicting yourself: You assume $c_1,c_2\neq 0$, but then loop to $\mathbf c=0$ (the conclusion is right, all that changes is that you're done 2 sentences earlier).
And finally, the part "Now, consider two eigenvectors $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_2$" is ambiguous, since you had already defined those two symbols (it'd be alright, though still not pretty, if you weren't using the old definitions of them afterwards again). Also, since we have multiple square matrices, we need to specify regarding which matrix they're eigenvectors.


In the above, $\mathbf{y}_i = c_i \mathbf{v}_i$ is also an eigenvector
of $\mathbf{A}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ ...

You still make the assertion that it's true, then go on to show it for many cases, and only then show it to be false for some cases. If you make an assertion, then you want to show it to be true, and handle cases where it's wrong even before making the assertion, in this case by making a case distinction.
For example:

In the above, $\mathbf{y}_i = c_i \mathbf{v}_i$ is either also an eigenvector
of $\mathbf{A}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ or $0$, since ...

Or you can drop the notion of eigenvector completely, since you go on to show the relevant equality anyway:

For the  $\mathbf{y}_i$ further holds that
$\mathbf{A} \mathbf{y}_i = \mathbf{A} (c_i \mathbf{v}_i) = c_i (\mathbf{A} \mathbf{v}_i) = c_i (\lambda_i \mathbf{v}_i) = \lambda_i (c_i \mathbf{v}_i)= \lambda_i \mathbf{y}_i$


In the last line of your proof

When $\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{0}$, it follows from the relation $ c_1 \mathbf{v}_1 \ + \ c_2 \mathbf{v}_2 \ + \ ... \ + \ c_n \mathbf{v}_n = \mathbf{0} $ that the eigenvectors are linearly independent.

the important part is that vectors are linearly independent iff the only way a linear combination of them sums to 0 is when all their coefficients are 0. Not, as you say, that the coefficients are $0$.
So, for example:

Since $\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{0}$ is the only solution, it follows from to the relation $ c_1 \mathbf{v}_1 \ + \ c_2 \mathbf{v}_2 \ + \ ... \ + \ c_n \mathbf{v}_n = \mathbf{0} $ that the eigenvectors are linearly independent.


But with these two minor corrections, we're finished.

Thanks for your comment. I have updated the proof. Please take a look.

I have modified the text. Thanks for all the help.
